# When is paint called in this program? Also, why does it extend canvas?

Tags: java, swing, awt

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GraphicsDemo1 extends Canvas
{
    public void paint( Graphics g )
    {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawRect(50,20,100,200);  // draw a rectangle
        g.fillOval(160,20,100,200); // draw a filled-in oval
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(200,400,200,20); // a filled-in rectangle
        g.drawOval(200,430,200,100);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("Graphics are pretty neat.", 500, 100);
        int x = getWidth() / 2;
        int y = getHeight() / 2;
        g.drawString("The first letter of this string is at (" + x + "," + y + ")", x, y);
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // You can change the title or size here if you want.
        JFrame win = new JFrame("GraphicsDemo1");
        win.setSize(800,600);
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GraphicsDemo1 canvas = new GraphicsDemo1();
        win.add( canvas );
        win.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks. awt and swing are very confusing to me.

Comment: A Question should be self-contained.  Links to ephemeral "code dumping" sites lead to Questions that become meaningless when the link breaks.

Comment: Don't extend Canvas, that is an AWT component. Instead extend JPanel and then override the `paintComponent()` method when you do custom painting.

Comment: A call to `super.paint` would also be a good idea, but camickr suggestion is a better place to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does it extend canvas?

Because who ever wrote it chose to do so.  Only those classes that extend from `Component` can actually be painted to the screen and only when they are attached to a valid, visible window

> When is paint called in this program?

Painting is the responsibility of the `RepaintManager`.  It will decide when components need to be repainted and schedule a repaint event on the Event Dispatching Thread.  This in turn calls (in your case `update` which calls) `paint` on your behalf.

You might like to have a read through [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details on the subject

Answer (score 1):

paint() is called whenever the control is invalidated and needs to repaint itself. Think of moving the app partially off screen and then back. Paint would get called to redraw...

I suppose a number of different controls could be extended to achieve the same goal which is basically to create a custom-drawn control. An existing control is extended to get the ability to draw on its surface, be placed in a JFrame, get repainted automatically etc.